# How do I input & output Japanese characters (kana) to the console in C#?

Tags: c#, encoding, console-application, cjk

After a bit of Googling, I figured out how to print out Japanese characters to the console using `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`.

I was hoping I'd also be able to take them in as an input with `Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` however that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

I tried to convert it from `string` to `byte[]` & back based on suggestions online, but that didn't seem to help much:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input); // Even tried Encoding.UTF8...
input = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

I would like to use a `wchar_t` equivalent, but I can't seem to find one.

```
// the entire program.
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; // works for output, after adjusting console font
Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; // didn't help, thought I'd get lucky

Console.WriteLine("Test a kana: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

// is it working yet?
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

How do I input & output Japanese characters (kana) to the console in C#?

Comment: Try setting the encoding to Unicode - `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode` & `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode`

Comment: Are you using the Windows Console? What do you see when the output is incorrect? Have you tried using the newer Windows Terminal, which supports UTF-8?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Why did that work? Everything I read, every post talked about making sure it was UTF8.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary To receive a kana as input, and be able to print it (to console), `InputEncoding` must be set to UTF8, or it will display the <?>. `OutputEncoding` can be set to either while still being able to print to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the input encoding to Unicode:

`Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`

Comment: Thanks Ermiya! I spent about a day and a half looking for a solution before posting here, and everything I read said to use `Encoding.UTF8`, I never would have thought to go to Unicode. I was able to set the `OutputEncoding` and `InputEncoding` and it's working without any issue.

Comment: `Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;` worked perfectly.

Comment: You’re welcome, no worries! :)